# React native android absolute position flatlist problem?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

In Android, my absolute components do not appear in the flatlist. There is no such problem on iOS. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? I need to stack my components on top of each other so I use absolute. If there is no solution, is there a way to stack them on top of each other without using absolute?